# Flex boxes center of page after max height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I set a max width and height for my flex boxes for responsive pages. After it surpasses the max height and width the boxes no longer become positioned in the center of the page even though I have `justify-content: center;` on my `.flex-container`. What am I doing wrong here? Anything helps, thanks!
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ColeGwoz/pen/ZxagqG?editors=1100)

```css
.flex-container {
    display:flex; justify-content: center;}

.flex-post { 
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height:auto;
    max-height:270px;
    max-width:270px;}

.flex-post:before {
    content:'';
    float:left;
    padding-top:100%;}

.flex-post:hover { 
    background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.5);}
```

```html
<div>
 
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-post">1</div>
    <div class="flex-post">2</div>
    <div class="flex-post">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-post">4</div>
    <div class="flex-post">5</div>
    <div class="flex-post">6</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-post">7</div>
    <div class="flex-post">8</div>
    <div class="flex-post">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to center the containers.

Add this to your code:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaYzxP?editors=1100)

Note that block elements consume the full width of their parent, by default. This behavior, however, does not extend to height ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)).

Comment: Your right it does work, but I was trying it on IE 11 and apparently it doesn't on here. Worked when I switched to chrome, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

```
.flex-post {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 270px;
  max-width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: While this may fix the issue, edit your answer to WHY this fixes the issue, not just code.